# AngularJs search and pagination code duplication

Tags: angularjs

Some modules of the application I'm writing give the user the option to filter a dataset and paginate the results.

After getting everything to work as intended, I'm trying to refactor the code in order to remove code duplication.

Each and everyone of the afore mentioned modules share the same bit of logic for filtering and pagination.

I'm wondering which is the best practice to follow in order to remove that kind of duplication.

As of now I was thinking of creating a "filter and pagination" service with the following API:

- Paginate(items,predicate,itemsPerPage)
  Returns an object:
  { 
  paginatedItems
  nrOfPages
  }

Predicate is called for each and every item passed in the collection, and it is used
to select items based on user preferences.

Now each module would take advantage of that API.

Is there a better, recomended way?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you doing the paging and the filtering on the client side or the server side? From the code above, it seems that you might be doing it on the client side (passing in the items array as the first argument).

Comment: Yes, I'm filtering and paginating on client's side